# Is there a way to convert complex number to just number?

Tags: python, integer

So I have this long number (i.e: 1081546747036327937), and when I cleaned up my data in pandas dataframe, I didn't realize Python converted it to complex number (i.e: 1.081546747036328e+18).

I saved this one as csv. The problem is, I accidentally deleted the original file, tried to recover it but no success this far, so...
is there a way to convert this complex number back to their original number?

I tried to convert it to str using str(data) but it stays the same (i.e: 1.081546747036328e+18).

Comment: That's not a complex number.  It's a floating point number, displayed with scientific notation.  If you want to convert it to an integer, use `int(n)`.

Comment: "anynumber"e+18 means "anynumber" multiply by 10 X 18  it is shorthand for writing big numbers

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Yugandhar Chaudhari it's 10 to the power of 18, not 10 times 18, just to be clear for the op :)

Comment: @Jens yes I ll correct myself 10 ** 18 please note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you were said in comment, this is not a complex number, but a floating point number. You can certainly convert it to a (long) integer, but you cannot be sure to get back the initial number.

In your example:

```
i = 1081546747036327937
f = float(i)
j = int(f)
print(i, f, j, j-i)
```

will display:

```
1081546747036327937 1.081546747036328e+18 1081546747036327936 -1
```

This is because floating points only have a limited accuracy and rounding errors are to be expected with large integers when the binary representation requires more than 53 bits.

Answer (score 2):

As can be read [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/complex/), complex numbers are a sum of a real part and an imaginary part.

> 3+1j is a complex number with the real value 3 and a complex value 1

You have a [scientific notation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/scientific.html) (type is [float](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/float/index.html)), which is just an ordinary float multiplied by the specified power of 10.

> 1e10 equals to 1 times ten to the power of ten

To convert this to int, you can just convert with **int(number)**. For more information about python data types, you can take a look [here](https://realpython.com/python-data-types/)